# Почему некорректно добавляются элементы в список?

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать код таким образом что при нажатие на кнопку `Добавить список` добавлялся список в котором нумеровался заголовок  и элементы. Проблема заключается в том что постоянно добавляется последний список(Шестой).

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const trigger = event.target.closest('span');
    if (trigger) {
        trigger.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
});
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
addBtn.addEventListener('click',function () {
    let counter = 0;
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('item');
    if (counter === 0) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Третий список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">9 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">10 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">11 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
        list.appendChild(li);
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter === 1) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Четвертый список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">12 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">13 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">14 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter === 2) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Пятый список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">15 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">16 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">17 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
        counter++;
    }
    if (counter === 3) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Шестой список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">18 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">19 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">20 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
        counter++;
    }

});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 55px;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.button {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 2px solid #0000bb;
    cursor: pointer;

    color: white;
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px darkblue;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    color: cyan;
}
.title::before {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    content: '-';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -15px;
}
.title.hide::before {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    content: '+';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -15px;
}
.extra-list {
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    max-height: 250px;
    color: snow;
    max-width: 240px;
    width: 100%;
}

.title.hide {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.title.hide + ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}
.extra-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.extra-item::before {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #05f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
.extra-item:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.extra-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h2>Добавить список</h2>
            <button id="btn-add" class="button">Добавить список</button>
            <ul id="list" class="list">
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Первый список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">1 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">2 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">3 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">4 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Второй список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">5 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">6 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">7 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">8 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Перечитайте ваш код, а какой "корректности" идёт речь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Проблема заключается в том что постоянно добавляется последний список(Шестой).

Я добавил коментарии по коду что убрано и что добавлено в твой вариант...

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
list.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    const trigger = event.target.closest('span');
    if (trigger) {
        trigger.classList.toggle('hide');
    }
});
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
// вынести из обработчика
let counter = 0;
addBtn.addEventListener('click',function () {
    // добавить "защиту"
    if (counter > 3) return
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.classList.add('item');
    if (counter === 0) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Третий список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">9 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">10 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">11 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
    }
    if (counter === 1) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Четвертый список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">12 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">13 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">14 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
    }
    if (counter === 2) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Пятый список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">15 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">16 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">17 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
    }
    if (counter === 3) {
        li.innerHTML = '<span class="title">Шестой список</span>' +
            '<ul class="extra-list">' +
            '<li class="extra-item">18 элемент списка</li>'  +
            '<li class="extra-item">19 элемент списка</li>' +
            '<li class="extra-item">20 элемент списка</li>' +
            '</ul>'
    }
    // все инкременты убрать, оставить только такой и тут
    counter++;
    list.appendChild(li);

});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #3f51b5;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 55px;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1920px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.button {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 2px solid #0000bb;
    cursor: pointer;

    color: white;
}
.button:hover {
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px darkblue;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    color: cyan;
}
.title::before {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    content: '-';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -15px;
}
.title.hide::before {
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    content: '+';
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -15px;
}
.extra-list {
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.7s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20px;
    max-height: 250px;
    color: snow;
    max-width: 240px;
    width: 100%;
}

.title.hide {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.title.hide + ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
}
.extra-item {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.extra-item::before {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #05f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -2px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
}
.extra-item:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
}
.extra-item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div>
            <h2>Добавить список</h2>
            <button id="btn-add" class="button">Добавить список</button>
            <ul id="list" class="list">
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Первый список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">1 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">2 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">3 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">4 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <span class="title">Второй список</span>
                    <ul class="extra-list">
                        <li class="extra-item">5 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">6 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">7 элемент списка</li>
                        <li class="extra-item">8 элемент списка</li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: скажите пожалуйста для чего вы используете данную строку `if (counter > 3) return`

Comment: @NANO_996, так `counter++` увеличит счетчик, а больше и добавлять нечего...